# Rythm Template Inheritance

Tags: java, template-engine, rythm

We have a common header/footer template as parent template which we will reuse for 100 of sub templates. Extends directive is not supporting this...

When i go over the Rythm documentation, i found a way to achieve this by include/invoke directives but the primary purpose of include/invoke directive is to invoke common function. Extends directive is supporting in a reverse way by putting main template content with a render directive as a parent and header/footer template as a subtemplate but the realtime usecase is totally different

Is that my understanding right? Is there a way to solve my problem?

**Edited:**

I have coded like below to achieve it:

footer.html

```
@def header1() {
    <h3>This is footer1 section</h3>
}

@def header2() {
    <h3>This is footer2 section</h3>
}
```

template1.html

```
@include("footer.html")
@args String who
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world from Rythm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello @who</h1>
        @if(footer.equals("footer1){
            @header1();
        } else {
            @header2();
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

What i have done is with the help of include/invoke method invocation i have got the result but when i use extends it doesn't work. If it is possible can u solve my case using extends?

Comment: I don't understand why you say Extends directive not supporting that. The `@extends` directive is designed to implement templating layout. Please refer to http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/886606b3a7034088b991855bef8f89da

Comment: I have added sample code i use in my app. Please look into it.

Answer (score 2):

To use `@extends` to achieve the same effect, you should have:

**layout.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world from Rythm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @render()
    </body>
</html>
```

**header1.html**

```
<h3>This is footer1 section</h3>
```

**header2.html**

```
<h3>This is footer2 section</h3>
```

**template.html**

```
@extends(layout)
@args String who, String footer

<h1>Hello @who</h1>
@if(footer.equals("footer1")){
    @header1();
} else {
    @header2();
}
```